# How to set multiple columns to null if they have meet some condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has 8 columns, `Child0, Child1, Child2, Child3, Child4, Child5, Child6, Childx`.

If `Child0=Childx`, then `Child0=null` else `Child0` remains the same. The same logic applies to `Child1` - `Child 6`.

I can only think of:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN Child6=Childx then null 
    ELSE Child6
END AS CHILD6,
CASE 
    WHEN Child5=Childx then null 
    ELSE Child5
END AS CHILD5,
...
FROM TABLE
```

Is there some simple way to do that?

Comment: If you had a normalized table this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @SeanLange This table is an intermediate table. I create it in this way on purpose. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `NULLIF`:

```
SELECT NULLIF(Child0,Childx) Child0,
       NULLIF(Child6,Childx) Child6,
       ....
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I need to wait for another 7 mins to mark this as answer.